# How to do field mapping in azure search for complex json objects for example nested array

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have following problem 
I have a field mapping update to an index .Payload is complex where
I have:

```
{
    "type": "abc",
    "Party": [{
        "Type": "abc",
        "Id": "123",
        "Name": "manasa",
        "Phone": [{
            "Type": "Office",
            "Number": "12345"
        }]
    }]
}
```

And now I want to create a field for an index. The field name is phonenumber of type Collection(Edm.String)
where mapping is

```
{
"sourceFieldName" : "/Party/Phone/Number",
"targetFieldName" : "phonenumber",
"mappingFunction" : { "name" : "jsonArrayToStringCollection" }
}
```

In http post body
But still after indexing i get phone number result as null.That means the mapping went wrong.If you see the phone number in source json, it is inside a json array and it itself is an array and result needs to get stored inside a collection of a string.Is it possible how can I achieve this?
If this is not possible I atleast want field mapping till phone array ie., /Party/Phone/

If i index complete party array as a text, I get an error while running the index saying:

```html
"Field 'partydetails' contains a term that is too large to process. The max length for UTF-8 encoded terms is 32766 bytes. The most likely cause of this error is that filtering, sorting, and/or faceting are enabled on this field, which causes the entire field value to be indexed as a single term. Please avoid the use of these options for large fields."
```

Can someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

Note that Party and Phone are arrays, so the field mapping you mention won't work.

You will need to index into the specific element.  For example:

```
{
    "sourceFieldName": "/Party/0/Phone/0/Type",
    "targetFieldName": "firstPhoneNumberTypeOfFirstParty"
}
```

You may want to give that a shot.

Thanks!

Luis Cabrera | Program Manager | Azure Search

Comment: Yes I got that confirmation from azure search team yesterday. But the thing is that's not suiting the requirement. So I need to transform the json to flat structure rather than having the nested structure. I am afraid it costs lot of performance for us to every time transform the json structure when ever new request come to us( we have million of records and get almost 10% of it everyday) and then index. So both of these are not feasible. So I guess I need to deal with it :) . Thanks anyway

Comment: If you know that your documents have at most 3 (for example) parties, you can have 3 field mappings: `/Party/0/Phone/0/Type`, `/Party/0/Phone/1/Type` and `/Party/0/Phone/2/Type` for index fields phone1, phone2, phone3 respectively. Obviously this doesn't work well if you have dozens of phone numbers, but can work fine if you only have a few.

Comment: In addition to picking a fixed number of `party` elements as suggested in earlier response, you may consider using the `jsonArray` parsing mode to index all phone numbers for each document with the root `/Party/Phone`. See [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-json-blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-index-json-blobs).
If you go down this path, you'll likely want to provide some "back pointer" in the phone number structure to reference the party id.

Answer (score 1):

If party would have been a Json object than an array and phone would have been only a string array for example

```
{
    "type": "abc",
    "Party": {
        "Type": "abc",
        "Id": "123",
        "Name": "manasa",
        "Phone": [{
            "12345",
            "23463"
        }]
    }
}
```

Then I could have mapped

```
{
    "sourceFieldName" : "Party/Phonenumber",
    "targetFieldName" : "phonenumbers",
    "mappingFunction" : { "name" : "jsonArrayToStringCollection" }
}
```

It map as collection of type odata EDM.string.

So to put this in better and straight forward way,

1. Either transform your json to something flatter (the example that I
   gave above) or
2. Use the proper index incase if you know before inhand as
       @Luis Cabrera said,

   ```
       “sourceFieldName”: “/Party/0/Phone/0/Type
   ```

It is a limitation from azure search side.