# Create azure search index from multiple collection with one to many fields mapping

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

If I take Hotel and Rooms example as per in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources

My data structure looks like this.

Hotels collection:

```
{
    "HotelId": "10",
    "HotelName": "Countryside Hotel",
    "Description": "Save up to 50% off traditional hotels.  Free WiFi, great location near downtown, full kitchen, washer & dryer, 24\/7 support, bowling alley, fitness center and more.",
    "Description_fr": "Économisez jusqu'à 50% sur les hôtels traditionnels.  WiFi gratuit, très bien situé près du centre-ville, cuisine complète, laveuse & sécheuse, support 24\/7, bowling, centre de fitness et plus encore.",
    "Category": "Budget",
    "Tags": [ "24-hour front desk service", "coffee in lobby", "restaurant" ],
    "ParkingIncluded": false,
    "LastRenovationDate": "1999-09-06T00:00:00Z",
    "Rating": 2.70,
    "Address": {
      "StreetAddress": "6910 Fayetteville Rd",
      "City": "Durham",
      "StateProvince": "NC",
      "PostalCode": "27713",
      "Country": "USA"
    },
    "Location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [ -78.940483, 35.904160 ]
    },
    "Rooms": [
        {
            "Id": "430a23c1-1f71-4719-9a10-450d06514d49",
            "Floor":2
        },
        {
            "Id": "7ff94ef5-e19b-4e16-926d-92d6e5be8ae2",
            "Floor":1
        },
        {
            "Id": "39f576da-3ce2-404c-a26f-cbd32e6dc355",
            "Floor":1
        }
    ]
}

Rooms collection:
{
    "Id": "430a23c1-1f71-4719-9a10-450d06514d49",
    "Floor":2,
    "Type": "Budget Room",
    "BaseRate": 96.99,
    "BedOptions": "1 Queen Bed",
    "SleepsCount": 2,
    "SmokingAllowed": true,
    "Tags": [ "vcr/dvd" ]
},
{
    "Id": "7ff94ef5-e19b-4e16-926d-92d6e5be8ae2",
    "Floor":1,
    "Type": "Budget Room",
    "BaseRate": 80.99,
    "BedOptions": "1 King Bed",
    "SleepsCount": 2,
    "SmokingAllowed": true,
    "Tags": [ "vcr/dvd", "jacuzzi tub" ]
},
{
    "Id": "39f576da-3ce2-404c-a26f-cbd32e6dc355",
    "Floor":10,
    "Type": "Deluxe Room",
    "BaseRate": 150.99,
    "BedOptions": "2 Double Beds",
    "SleepsCount": 2,
    "SmokingAllowed": false,
    "Tags": [ "suite", "bathroom shower", "coffee maker" ]
}
```

I have one cosmos collection for Hotels. Another cosmos collection for Rooms. Here lets say Hotels are configurable. When you create Hotel object you pick and add rooms from Rooms collection(Drag and drop to hotel in UI). But not all the fields related to that room is stored in the Hotel/Rooms.

Now I want to build search index on Hotel collection with complete Room information.
My approach was to create Index schema based on Hotel. And then Rooms indexer pointing to the same index with field mapping. I have tried the below field mappings

```
var map = new List<FieldMapping>{ new FieldMapping { SourceFieldName = "Id", TargetFieldName = "/Rooms/*/Id" } };

Indexer cosmosDbIndexer = new Indexer(
name: indexerName,
dataSourceName: cosmosDbDataSource.Name,
targetIndexName: indexName,
fieldMappings: map);
```

But I am getting error "TargetField /Rooms/*/Id does not exists in the index". But the index has Rooms collection of complex type with "Id" field.

Please help me with the proper mapping. I need complete room document to replace what I have in Hotel.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. It sounds like you have multiple data sources that each contain data for what will be a complex type collection in the index, and the question is how you would map the complex type collection into different fields rather than the same. If you're trying to just rename the top level field, take a look at field mappings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings).

Comment: Mapping complex collection items has its limitations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151575/how-to-do-field-mapping-in-azure-search-for-complex-json-objects-for-example-nes . Let me know if that was helpful or if I got your question wrong. It would be helpful if you can detail your datasources set up and desired  index shape.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or why you would need a search index. Without understanding your problem I would say it sounds like a typical database problem. Perhaps it's easier to explain if you describe a use case with actual or mockup data?

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: The question is much clearer now. I don't have an answer for you though. I would typically merge the data and produce the records using custom code that does not rely on specific features Azure Search features. One tip would be to check out the comment in the Overview section you link to (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources#overview) where they point out a difference in Azure.Search.Documents (version 11) vs Microsoft.Azure.Search (version 10) . Which one are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Field mapping to a subfield is not supported. The target of the field mapping must be a top-level index field, which is why you're seeing the error message. +1 to Dan's suggestion of merging the data prior to indexing.